# How to store extra header value with MailCore2?

Tags: objective-c, mailcore, mailcore2

I add an extra header value with MailCore2:

```
MCOMessageHeader *messageHeader = message.header; 
[messageHeader setExtraHeaderValue:spamScoreString forName:@"Spam Score"];
```

How can I save this new header value to the **IMAP** server?

I have already searched for sample code and I have also read the class reference for MCOMessageHeader (which, by the way, states the wrong method name - `(void)addHeaderValue:(NSString *)`value `forName:(NSString *)name`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

editWith the help of dinhviethoa in the MailCore2 forum on GitHub (https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/issues/680), the question could be answered:

- It is not possible to edit the header of an existing email.
- However, it is possible to remove the existing message from the server and append a new message (with extra headers).